# Document is centered when compiled on Mac but not when compiled on PC

Tags: formatting

When I compile my amsart document, with default page formatting, on my Mac using TeXShop editor, the text is centered in the pdf.  When I compile the same code using my PC with either TeXworks or TeXstudio, the text shifts slightly to the right in the pdf.  Then when I add the argument [a4paper] to the amsart document class, the text becomes centered when compiled on my PC.

How can I fix this so that the default page formatting (US letter size) results in a centered document when compiled on my PC?

It seems like this has nothing to do with my code, only the difference between my computers.

My PC is a ThinkPad Yoga 14.  The problem occurs with the following example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1





\end{document}
```

Comment: It has something to do with your code - the behaviour depends a lot on the used packages and the options - so show a complete minimal example.

Comment: I do not understand how it can have something to do with my code.  Someone using my mac would see there is no problem.  Someone using my PC would see there is a problem.  Same code.

Comment: I know what is your problem. But without code I can't tell you which option(s) you need to add.

Comment: OK I did what you said, but it feels silly.  I still do not understand how in theory it can have anything to do with the code.  But I'm sure I will be proved wrong, since I know nothing about computers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

amsart is old and has no notion about the pdf size. So without changes you get whatever your tex system sets as default - which can be a4paper or letter.

You can e.g. load the graphicx package which will set the correct values. Then your document will be always in letter format:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing, it works!  Thanks a lot.  Told you I don't know anything about computers;)